# Apply theme in magento2

Tags: magento, themes

I have just downloaded magento 2 and have theme downloaded separately. I want to apply this theme in magento for which I will have to copy the theme folder in magento. My theme folder contains 3 directories - app, js, skin. Dont get how to copy it in magento and kickstart?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like your theme is compatible with Magento 1 because it contains skin and js folder. But in Magento 2 there are no such folders.

Comment: Thanks Miraj, Your answer made my day. I spent yesterday whole day searching solution for it. Thanks a lot, Once again